# How to disable TestFlight beta testing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm not able to transfer my application to iTunes connect. It is said that I have to disable my Beta testing of the application. Actually, I have stopped testing, deleted all builds from beta testing. App was set up for only internal testers. I have removed all testers as well. But still same issue. Here is the snap.

[image]

Comment: had you tried by expiring all the build on test flight?

Comment: Yes, I did. There were two builds in TestFlight, I expired both of them.

Comment: Hi @AshwinIndianic did you find any solution for this? I am facing this too :(

Comment: No dear not yet, Waiting for the comment from the apple team

Comment: I have sent an email to Apple too. Let us write here when we got a response :)

Comment: Sure I will, Please update me as well once you got the answer.

Comment: Re-contacted to apple team. Do you get any solution?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, Have you managed to resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Same problem, boring

Comment: No any updated from my client abut apple's replay as my client is out of the station... I shall update here once finds any solution or here from apple.

Answer (score 8):

I spoke with an Apple representative on the phone regarding this issue. They are aware of this bug and working on it. That's all she could answer me.
Try again next week, if the issue is still there (which probably will be), I had to call again...

Comment: I tried to contact apple team twice, but don't know why they did not reply to me. Anyway thank for updates

Comment: I called an Apple representative on the phone, they are still working on the issue, no time estimation of it being solved.

Comment: 4 years later and it's 2020 and I guess they're still working on it. lol

Answer (score 8):

Pay attention to application localization. If your application has support multi language, then you could leave the information in the TestFlight menu.

You must delete the test information not only from the main language, but from other languages that are supported in your application. Go to **TestFlight** tab -> **Test Information**. Then click blue button with your language in right side of webpage. You shall choose other language supported in your application and remove all appeared information about testing. After this, click `Save` button ([see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBCK.png))

And try to transfer app. Next to the text **TestFlight Beta Testing** should be a green checkmark.

P.S. This solution was suggested by the Apple Support Team. Here is a part of their letter:

> After checking your iTunes Connect account, we could see that you have
>   started to test a build internally, and you still have a feedback
>   email listed under Test Information in the English (U.S.)
>   localization. Therefore, I would kindly ask you to expire the build
>   and remove the feedback email.
>   After you have followed the information above, you should be able to
>   proceed further with your transfer.

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. Thanks for the updates

Answer (score 2):

**Remove all testers and all testing information** from the application in iTunesConnect on tab TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all testers, all builds (detail each one and expire it) and remove all information about how to test the app. I did this and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this bug going to TestFlight section in Appstoreconnect and in Test Information switch to another language and clear all field also there.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

If nothing helps, maybe these steps will help you.
You have to go to the TestFlight tab, then Test Information, and in the top right corner press language button. If you have more than one language, delete them from the list.